# Selecting unique value SQL

Tags: sql

When running this SQL query it returns each Find_ID four times, how can I make it only select unique finds?

```
SELECT A.FIND_ID, B.NAME, PERIOD
FROM FINDS A, CLASS B
WHERE A.X >= 4
AND A.X <= 10
AND A.Y >= 4
AND A.Y <= 10
AND FIND_ID = DISTINCT
```

This returns

```
FIND_ID NAME                 PERIOD
========== ==================== ====================
         2 SHARD                BRONZE
         5 SHARD                BRONZE
         2 METAL_WORK           IRON_AGE
         5 METAL_WORK           IRON_AGE
         2 FLINT                MESOLITHIC
         5 FLINT                MESOLITHIC
         2 BONE                 RECENT
         5 BONE                 RECENT
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc.. can you also give sample data with desired result?

Comment: Maybe a `group by A.FIND_ID` or `SELECT DISTINCT(A.FIND_ID)`

Comment: Google for "carthesian product"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two tables FINDS and CLASS are related you need to be using some kind of join (INNER, at a guess).  The reason why you are getting four results is that you are running a query that returns the cartesian product of your results - that is, you will get all combinations of both tables joined together without a common field linking the two of them together.

Here's an example.  Let's say you have the two really simple tables below:-

```
PersonID   Name
1           Matt
2           Fred

PersonID   Salary
1           23000
2           18000
```

Then a query like:-

```
SELECT * FROM Person, Salary
```

Would return something like:-

```
PersonID  Name  PersonID  Salary
1         Matt  1         23000
2         Fred  2         18000
1         Matt  2         18000
2         Fred  1         23000
```

Et voila, four records where you might expect two.  Adding DISTINCT to this would achieve nothing, as each of the rows is distinct.  To link the related tables you would need something like:-

```
SELECT * FROM Person INNER JOIN Salary ON Person.PersonID = Salary.PersonID
```

Comment: Fantastic! I have solved my problem! Will need to wait before posting answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use the distinct property.. Select Distinct(SAMPLE) From table1

Comment: what if the record has different `PERIOD` on the same `ID` and `NAME`?

Comment: It will display all distinct records, run the query and see your results. You can figure that out by looking at it

Comment: The problem I am having is that returns the same find for each A.x >=4 statment, entering DISTINCT(A.FIND_ID) does not solve it.